# Solve warning message for sem in lavaan (RStudio)

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

Good morning,
I'm trying to run my first SEM in RStudio through laavan, with the following model.

```
mod <- '
# measurement model
comprG =~ ALTRAPROF + ITAPROFIC
Uso =~ RELAZIONI + CASA + SOCIETA
Bambini =~ Articolazione + Denominazione
# regressions
comprG ~ SESEdu 
Uso ~ SESEdu 
comprG ~ Uso
Uso ~ comprG 
AREA_VERBALE ~ Uso + comprG + SESEdu
Bambini ~ AREA_VERBALE
'
```

However, I get the same warning message that has been previously exposed in other topic but still I cannot solve it through the previous answers:

```
Warning messages:
1: In lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
  lavaan WARNING:
    Could not compute standard errors! The information matrix could
    not be inverted. This may be a symptom that the model is not
    identified.
2: In lav_object_post_check(object) :
  lavaan WARNING: some estimated lv variances are negative.
```

I suppose as a consequence of this warnings, my output return NA values for std. dev and do not return p values and z scores.
Can you please help me to solve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello. Your question may be off-topic as it asks about fixing error messages and purely programming questions are not on topic on Cross Validated. And in any case, you may need to revise your question to provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, to provide data to reproduce the error.

Comment: There are threads discussing this same lavaan error message on Stack Overflow: [Model identification in lavaan for R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44114501/9566484), which could be of help. And finally, you can enclose code snippets with three backticks to format it properly.